# how to make two apps open and close together when i open one of them

Tags: automation, application-launch

I want MSI afterburner to start when I open a game and close when I close the game. is there any way to do this automatically? I tried creating a task with the task scheduler but the farthest I got was [here](https://pasteboard.co/7jGLxOhyQ71Z.png)

Comment: Do you know any programming languages?

Comment: Only one specific game? Or many?

Comment: i want to do it for many games, and no I don't know any programming languages

Comment: I would recommend learning a simple programming language. This is a nice little first project.

Comment: I have been wanting to learn some programming language too, and I tried learning python; I just don't know where to start

Comment: as for the post, is there something I can do in task scheduler?

Comment: Task Scheduler won't work for this purpose. You can try https://www.learnpython.org/ or google "free python course", there are many available